# jQuery - func append , the first one has appear twice

Tags: jquery, append

I want to add some details to the tag 'li', so I storage the details into a tag 'a'.

But it doesn't work well. The index '0' appears twice.

The related code.

```
<div class="frame">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="thumb" href="#" />        
                <img title="EOC 450D Camera" src="image/picture1.jpg"/>
                <a class= "descript" href="test1" />

            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="thumb" href="#"/>
                    <img title="A Set of Camera Lenses" src="image/picture2.jpg"/>
                <a class = "descript" href="test2" />

            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="thumb" href="#"/>
                    <img title="Profession Camera" src="image/picture3.jpg"/>
                <a class= "descript" href="test3" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="thumb" href="#">
                    <img title="EOC 2100D Camera" src="image/picture4.jpg"/>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery part:

```
$items.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this), 
            _href = $this.find('a').attr('href'), 
            _title = $this.find('img').attr('title');
        var _text = $this.find('.descript').attr('href');

        $this.append('<div class="ovrly">' +
            '<h3>' + 
                '<a href="' + _href + '" alt="' + _title + '" title="' + _title + '">' + _title + '</a>'  + 
            '</h3>' + '<br>' + _text +
            '</div>').find('.ovrly').css('opacity', _opacity);
    });
```

But the effect is like this.
[image: the test1 has appeared twice!]

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the browser is getting confused with your self-closing `<a ... />` elements. If you change them all to have separate closing `</a>` tags then it seems to work fine.

That is, change:

```
<a class="thumb" href="#" />
```

to

```
<a class="thumb" href="#"></a>
```

And so forth. Although probably each `<img>` element should be within the first anchor for each `<li>`, like you've done with the fourth one.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5jp0f3or/

(Running your code in Chrome, I tried `console.log( $("a").length );` and it showed `13`! Closing all the anchors with `</a>` and trying again it logged the expected `7`.)